# How do I escape '\x' in Python?

Tags: python, json, escaping

I'm using `pymysql` to query a database that has an entry like `'name':'Te\xtCorp'`, it's a name that I need to preserve. I'm sending it somewhere else with `json.dumps()` and when it hits this it fails to escape the `\x`.

What's the proper way to escape the `\x` without double escaping everything else?

Comment: What do you mean, "without double escaping everything else"? What approach are you currently attempting which has that side effect?

Comment: `json.dumps()` already escapes my payloads, it just fails on `\x` in this one entry for some reason.

Comment: Unless you are typing the string literal `'Te\xtCorp'`, you shouldn't need to do *anything*. You need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Someone did type the string `Te\xtCorp`, and then it was saved in the database I'm querying.

Comment: @Strelok: but how did you save it in the database, because usually the database will escape it itself.

Comment: @Strelok, ...and? How is the JSON code escaping it that's wrong? Generally, that'll encode to `"Te\\xtCorp"`, which would be the *correct* way to encode that literal string as JSON. (If you're seeing the `repr()` representation of that it'll be `'"Te\\\\xtCorp"'`, but that's just the Python representation of the string rather than its literal value).

Comment: `json.dumps()` is throwing an error and ending the script. I've found that the actual issue is the string `Psonre\xede` is what's failing which is `Psonríe` and the problem is not just `\x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options here:

1. You **escape the backslash**, like:

   ```
   'Te\\xtCorp'
   ```
2. You can use a **raw string**:

   ```
   r'Te\xtCorp'
   ```

Both generate:

```
>>> 'Te\\xtCorp'
'Te\\xtCorp'
>>> r'Te\xtCorp'
'Te\\xtCorp'
```

Or printed:

```
>>> print(r'Te\xtCorp')
Te\xtCorp
```

Note that in order to inspect the **content** of the string, you should use a `print(..)` statement, otherwise you get the `repr(..)`esentation of that string. For example:

```
>>> print(json.dumps(r'te\xt'))
"te\\xt"
>>> print(json.loads(json.dumps(r'te\xt')))
te\xt
```

---

As one can read in the [*documentation on String literals*](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html):

> `\xhh...`: ASCII character with hex value `hh...`

So it is used to encode any ASCII character, by specifying the code as a hexadecimal value.

Comment: If I replace all of `\x ` with `\\x ` and then give it to `json.dumps()` I'll get `\\\\x` for other cases that it's handling just fine now like `te\st` I'll get `te\\st`

Comment: @Strelok: I think your code formatting on the comment has gone wrong. Can you please try to repost it (or edit your question for instance)?

Comment: I noticed and have fixed it

Comment: @Strelok: How did you replace the string?

Comment: I just typed `json.dumps(r'te\xt')` into the python prompt to test it out

Comment: Then when `json.load()` gets it again somewhere down the line it'll be `Te\\xtCorp` which isn't correct.

Comment: @Strelok: you have to **print** the result of `json.dump(..)` in order to get the **real** string. Right now you see Pythons representation of that string. If you write `print(json.dumps(r'te\xt'))` you see two backslashes.

Comment: @Strelok: the same comment applies to your second comment. The Python representation of `te\xt` is `'te\\xt'`.

Comment: @Strelok: see edited answer.